# Binder to string

Tags: c#, asp.net-2.0

how to put  `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Code") %>` to string in aspx file?
like `<% string str = DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Code") %>`?
I am getting error The name 'Container' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I need to put image in datagrid but not in every line, i need to put the image where code has some name

Comment: Why not write a helper function in your code behind to which you would pass the current item and which will return the required string? I have posted an example as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a helper function in your code behind which will return the required string:

```
protected string MyFunction(object item)
{
    ... do some calculations and return a string
}
```

and then in your view whenever you needed the value you could call this function:

```
<%# MyFunction(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Code")) %>
```

This way you no longer need a variable.